# Unable to installed cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I am Unable to installed `cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing` and also try cmd with administrator

```
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

Comment: please dont paste error text as image

Comment: Also you can try `npm cache clean -f`

Comment: Suraj Rao Thank you it works

Comment: @SurajRao could you please add that as an answer? :)

Comment: was hoping to find a duplicate @sebaferreras

Comment: Oh yes, I've tried as well but couldn't find an "exact" duplicate. Thanks @SurajRao

Answer (score 2):

In such cases you need to clear the npm cache and try.

```
npm cache clean -f
```